# Deploy a rails application in a sub-directory with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, mod-proxy

I have a website : http://foo.com
I would like to add a rails application in : http://foo.com/subdir
So I use a Apache Proxy to do it.

In the server with the Rails application, I have Passenger and Apache, and my VirtualHost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 1.2.3.4

  DocumentRoot /path/to/railsapp/public
  RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I go to http://foo.com/subdir, all the paths are incorect (http://foo.com/images, http://foo.com/users, ... etc) but what I would like is a subdirectory like (http://foo.com/subdir/images, http://foo.com/subdir/users, ... etc)

So how could I do it please ?

PS : I tried [RailsBaseURI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri), but it don't work :(.

Comment: RailsBaseURI works as specified. Just follow documentation.

Comment: If I add "RailsBaseURI /subdir" to my VirtualHost, it return 404 it my foo.com/subdir.
Maybe it's because I'm behind a Apache Proxy ?

Comment: Did you create symbolic link as described in documentation?

Comment: Yes : "ln -s public subdir" in my rails directory ?

Comment: Link should be created in document root, not in rails directory.

Comment: Ok, so I go in public dir and I do "ln -s . subdir" but it still the same (http://etu.utt.fr/v9/ if you want to see it)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4367/discussion-between-dorian-and-alexd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my application to `subdir/`

I created a .htaccess with :

```
PassengerEnabled on
PassengerAppRoot /path/to/railsapp/subdir
```

And my VirtualHost :

```
  DocumentRoot /path/to/railsapp/  
  <Directory /path/to/railsapp/subdir>
    AllowOverride All
    RailsBaseURI /subdir
  </Directory>
```

Thanks AlexD for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions on the passenger site are very good for this now:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Answer (score 1):

Ended up here from a Google search, so thought I would share the up-to-date info regarding this.

See Passenger's documentation for [Deploying an app to a sub-URI or subdirectory](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri-or-subdirectory/).

`RailsBaseURI` / `RackBaseURI` are deprecated, use `PassengerBaseURI`.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I don't have any manually deployed passenger app so I can't personally test that

Comment: The howto page also has moved. I found the following page.
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/

Comment: Good catch yosei! I edited the answer and changed the link